# HDDs won't spin down with hdparm command

Tags: debian, power-management, hdparm

I am using Debian Jessie on a HP Proliant Microserver Gen8 with two Western Digital Red 3TB. No RAID or anything else.
I wanted the HDDs to automatically spin down after two hours. 
Triggering it manually works fine with both commands

```
sudo hdparm -Y /dev/sda

sudo hdparm -y /dev/sda
```

so the output then is

```
user@NAS:~$ sudo hdparm -C /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 drive state is:  standby
```

But when I use:

```
sudo hdparm -S 244 /dev/sda
```

the HDD won't go into any kind of standby mode. Note that sda is not the system drive. I mounted both HDDs via fstab like this:

```
UUID=xxx       /mnt/Stuff                                ext4    defaults,noatime,nodiratime        0       0
```

Any idea why this won't work? I also tried 10 seconds and 1 minute. Is there a way to determine if there is any process accessing the partitions on the HDDs? I do use a DLNA Server and Samba, but no access has been made by me during the test, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`iosnoop`](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/iosnoop) (available in the [`perf-tools-unstable`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/utils/perf-tools-unstable) package in Debian), you can trace activity on a specific device:

```
iosnoop -d 8,0
```

will show you what processes are accessing the device. That should allow you to determine what is waking your drives up.

To determine the device number to use, look at the major/minor device numbers for the nodes:

```
ls -l /dev/sd*
```

You can also run `iosnoop` without arguments to monitor all I/O.

Answer (score 0):

i had kind of similar problem on my NAS with OpenWrt setup, but even `sudo hdparm -Y /dev/sda` didn't work. Hdd returned back to `active/idle` state in a second or half of. So, i mentioned that there is strange `ext4lazyinit` process. This thing triggered HDD with short perions of time. To get rid of it, just format ext4 with that parameters `mkfs.ext4 -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0 /dev/<your ext4 partition>`